# strange behaviour of primitive c++ memory logic

Tags: c++, memory, stm32, iar

In IAR IDE with stm32 (arm cortex) CPU I have very strange behaviour in a primitive situation.

```
uint32_t s = 6654; //=0x000019FE
//next I'll see in IAR debugger

uint8_t res1 = 0;
res1 = (s&0xFF000000)>>24;  //see in debugger: res1=00
res1 = (s&0x00FF0000)>>16;  //res1=00
res1 = (s&0x0000FF00)>>8;   //res1=19
res1 = (s&0x000000FF);      //res1=FE

void *sp = &s;
uint8_t res2 = 0;
res2 = *((uint8_t*)sp+0);   //res2=FE            but must be 00!
res2 = *((uint8_t*)sp+1);   //res2=19            but must be 00!
res2 = *((uint8_t*)sp+2);   //res2=00            but must be 19!
res2 = *((uint8_t*)sp+3);   //res2=00            but must be FE!
```

(See comments for what I expect, and what happens.)
Why am I getting this result? I have no explanations.

Comment: Read about [*endianness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: Do you get the same result every time?

Comment: Always write code in a way that will work no-matter what the endian. e.g. as you did for `res1`. The res2 code relies on how the 32 bit number is distributed in the 4 bytes of memory, this is not guaranteed by the C standard. The first example (res1) only relies on what the data represents, not on where it is.  (I have even seen processors that have different layouts: big-little endian, and little-big endian).

Answer (score 9):

It's just the *endianness* of your platform that confuses you: You expect a *Big endian* model, what you are observing via debugger is *Little endian*.

This article may help: [Endianness - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)